# Meteor helper doesn't work on template as expected

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I have the following code in my template's helper:

```
Template.ListPosts.helpers({
    drawingPosts: () => {
        return Drawings.find({});
    },
    userVoted: () => {
        if(Drawings.find({_id: this._id, votedUsers: {$in: [Meteor.userId()]}}).count() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
})
```

I can access the `drawingPosts` in the helper with no issues, but when I try to use `userVoted` as follows:

```
{{#if userVoted}}
    <i id="heart" class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 18px; position: relative; left: 110px; color: red"></i>
{{else}}
    <i id="heart" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 18px; position: relative; left: 110px"></i>
{{/if}}
```

the script inside `{{else}}` get executed even when I `console.log(Drawings.find({_id: this._id, votedUsers: {$in: [Meteor.userId()]}}).count())` I get 1, but inside the template, `userVoted` seems to be always `false`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you testing the `console.log` in your template helper or directly in the console ? If you did it in the console, try to `console.log` the statement (`Drawings.find`...) before the if and post the result please.

Comment: Which fontawesome version do you use? If you use Fontawesome 5, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60639157/if-currentuser-with-icon-inside-still-rendered-when-user-logs-out/60639984#60639984